# nutch on hadoop keeps quitting before completion

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I am running nutch 1.7 using a 3 node hadoop cluster. I entered more than 3000 urls in the seeds.txt file. The job finishes surprisingly fast with success status. When I check the results in solr, many of the urls returns nothing. Most of the ones that do have content only got one page's worth.

I retry just a single url which got no results before. Now it gets 94 pages of content. So the problem is definitely not due to robot rejection.

everytime I reran the entire list, it would run for sometime and get a few more page content, but never completes the list.

What could cause nutch to quit like that?

Comment: Can you share some links?

Comment: links? you mean the sites I want to crawl? why does that matter?

Comment: What is the output of hadoop.log? Would you please explain more about your problem? It could be thousand of scenarios that Nutch could not work. I need to know more about your problem.

Comment: I looked everywhere and don't see any error messages. What would you look for?

Comment: @user1058511 Something like timeout exception, parse error or anything that could cause such problem.

Comment: only found this: Diagnostics report from attempt_1428883737454_0298_r_000001_0: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.Container killed on request. Exit code is 143. some posting says related to reduce heap size. how to fix that?